# How to configure SSO and LDAP authentication in Maarch Courrier 1.5

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on, dms

I've installed a DMS called Maarch Courrier, an opensource alternative to SharePoint and Alfresco. I successfully configured  my Active Directory to work with it.

But on the first connexion, the software asks AD users to provide a new password to be used in Maarch. So, I'd like to setup Single Sign On with LDAP in the Maarch Courrier DMS. Following this tutorial : http://wiki.maarch.org/Socle_Technique_/_How_to_connect_a_SSO, I tried to configure it but failed. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the configuration file. You can find it in the ldap module

Comment: I configured the ldap module. And it's alright : I can log into maarch with my AD credentials. But Maarch asks me the first time I log in with my AD credentials, to write down a new password so that it will be used in my Maarch installation. And that is what I don't want. This is the reason why I would like to setup SSO together with Active Directory. But I don't know how. :(